# Can you hash an array in a yaml file with Hiera

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

I'm trying to use puppet to create a mysql user with a set of privileges using the puppetlabs-mysql module

My yaml looks like this:

```
  mysqlgrants:
  testuser@%{::ipaddress}/*.*  :  
    ensure    : 'present'
    options   : ['GRANT']
    privileges: ['SELECT','INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE']
    table     : '*.*'
    user      : "testuser@%{::ipaddress}"
```

I am then using the hiera_hash function to operate on mysqlgrants. This errors when the privileges value is an array, but is fine when the privileges value is just a single value e.g. ['ALL']. Does anyone know why?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: This is probably better asked/answered on http://serverfault.com

Comment: @PeterM meh, this errs on the programming side of Puppet, I guess.

Comment: @OP what is the manifest that makes use of this? Please check your paste, the YAML is malformed, but this might be a formatting error here. Finally, what is the error produced when not using `['ALL']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved:

to use hiera hash a key-value where the value is an array use:

```
mysqlgrants:
  testuser@%{::ipaddress}/*.*  :  
  ensure    : 'present'
  options   : ['GRANT']
  privileges:
    - SELECT
    - UPDATE
    - INSERT
    - DELETE
  table     : '*.*'
  user      : "testuser@%{::ipaddress}"
```

now in your manifest you can call hiera_hash(mysql_grant, mysqlgrants) without a syntax error